# Is there a way to set a string permission mode in mkdir() or chmod() in PHP?

Tags: php, mkdir

When I looked up the PHP Manual for mkdir() and chmod(), it appears that both functions expect an integer value (e.g. `mkdir( 'a/dir/path', 0700, false` ); ).  I did see that there are other modes I can use such as inval() or ocdec() on the mode parameter, so I'm wondering...*is there something like that for strings?*

For example, `mkdir( 'a/dir/path', strval( 'u+rwx' ), false );` .  The reason for this is so that when other people who are (also) not as experienced in PHP read my code, it will be more apparent what permissions I'm setting.

Comment: You could write a class and put `0700` in `const MY_PERM = '0700';`

Comment: Only as a note: I don't think that `u+rwx` is more intuitive than `0777`. If people that read the code knows something about permissions is same intuitive the string than the numbers. That's not PHP permissions. That's UNIX/Linux O.S. permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think that it is strictly necessary to implement that kind of function: numeric permissions are actually intuitive for those who know how to read them.

However, to answer the question, to convert a string like "**-rwxr-xrw-**" you could use something like this function:

**N.B.: you should REALLY add some input validation to the function below (check string length, valid chars, etc..)**

```
function format($permissions)
{
    //Initialize the string that will contain the parsed perms.
    $parsedPermissions = "";

    //Each char represents a numeric constant that is being added to the total
    $permissionsDef = array(
        "r" => 4,
        "w" => 2,
        "x" => 1,
        "-" => 0
    );

    //We cut the first of the 10 letters string
    $permissions = substr($permissions, 1);

    //We iterate each char
    $permissions = str_split($permissions);
    $length = count($permissions);

    $group = 0;

    for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < $length; $i++, $j++) {
        if ($j > 2) {
            $parsedPermissions .= $group;

            $j = 0;
            $group = 0;
        }
        $group += $permissionsDef[$permissions[$i]];
    }

    $parsedPermissions .= $group;

    return $parsedPermissions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no inbuilt way of doing it. I also do not think there is a need for it. A link to an explanation of file permissions and a comment such as this one from http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2003/02/06/php_foundations.html should suffice:

> ```
> Value   Permission Level
> --------------------------
> 400     Owner Read
> 200     Owner Write
> 100     Owner Execute
>  40     Group Read
>  20     Group Write
>  10     Group Execute
>   4     Global Read
>   2     Global Write
>   1     Global Execute
>
> Permission Calculations:
> ------------------------
>    400  Owner Read
> +  100  Owner Execute
> +   20  Group Write
> +    4  Global Read
> -----------------------------
> = 0524  Total Permission Value
> ```

This is easier than writing a function to **correctly** parse all the possible strings that can be used as file permissions.

Comment: Hey, thanks, everyone.  I learned something new and didn't realize that PHP permissions are better read with the int values until today (and that experience/learning how they work is key...).  Thanks again for your insights!